# Javascript scope issues with Revealing Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, scope

One more JavaScript scoping problem. I believe this is not related to 'hoisting'.

I've a small block of code here - http://jsfiddle.net/0oqLzsec/2/

```
var c = function(){
    var x = 'before',
        callBefore = function(){
            alert(x);
        },
        callAfter = function(){
            _callAfter();
        };

    return{
        callBefore : callBefore,
        callAfter : callAfter
    }

    var y = 'after';

    function _callAfter(){
        alert(y);
    }
};

var obj = c();
obj.callBefore();
obj.callAfter();
```

`callAfter()` always alerts 'undefined' even if the variable y is defined before `_callAfter()`. But If I move the variable y declaration before variable x it is working.

I'm wondering if `callAfter()` can `_callAfter()` which is defined below, why can't it read variable y?

Comment: It is a hoisting issue. The variable y declaration gets hoisted, but not the assignment.

Comment: "**One more** JavaScript scoping problem"? Your questions may or may not be seen by the same set of people every time, so that's a bit of a non sequitur...

Comment: it's simple, you return before you declare `y`, so it's undefined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to hoisting, `var y` is moved to the top of the function, but the assignment (`y = 'after'`) is not, so it never runs because it's after the `return statement`.

The JS engine rewrites your code to look something like:

```
var c = function(){           
    // functions also get hoisted to the top
    function _callAfter(){
        alert(y);
    }
    var x = 'before',
        callBefore = function(){
            alert(x);
        },
        callAfter = function(){
            _callAfter();
        },
        // y declaration is hoisted to the top of the function
        y;

    return {
        callBefore : callBefore,
        callAfter : callAfter
    };

    // the assignment never gets called because it's after the return
    y = 'after';
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`_callAfter` and `y` are both hoisted, which makes them known as local variables through the function invocation. The `_callAfter` function is able to be called (as you do), and it also closes over the variable `y`. However, this variable does not get a value *assigned* before you return from the `c` function. Thus, you get `undefined`. It is the same if you put `var y;` BEFORE the return, and `y='after';` after the return.

In other words, the following two are equivalent:

```js
function foo(){
  var a;
  return function(){ return a };
  a = 42; // never runs
}
alert( foo()() );

function bar(){
  return function(){ return a };
  var a = 42;
}
alert( bar()() );
```

Here's an example showing that the local variable is hoisted and closed over, even when the function literal occurs before the `var` in code:

```js
function build() {
  return function(newValue) {
    alert("was: " + oldValue);
    oldValue = newValue;
    alert("now: " + oldValue);
  }
  var oldValue = 42;
}

f = build();
f(17);
// was: undefined
// now: 17

f(99);
// was: 17
// now: 99
```